# When interrupting an application with spring boot @EnableScheduling tomcat will not shutdown application properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Application which is using the spring boot scheduling mechanism. The App is working fine but there is a problem when the tomcat server will stop or tries to redeploy the app.

What do I use:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class MyTask{
  
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public void findJobs() {
    //here the work will be done
}
```

I can start my app with appRun and when I aborting the appRun while there where job in processin it will abort but some threads are still available

Here the error messages:

```
 The web application appears to have started a thread named [ForkJoinPool.commonPool- 
 worker-11] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack 
 trace of thread:
```

I have reduced this to the minimal configuration, I had already a version where I created a ThreadPool and used the @PreDestroy hook to shutdown the Executor/ThreadPool but this also lead to this error. So any idea how I can fix this?

These Exceptions are visible in the Stacktrace

```
       Jan 13, 2022 9:38:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
    WARNING: The web application appears to have started a thread named [scheduling-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1782)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:4881)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.nextPacket(IOBuffer.java:4791)



    Jan 13, 2022 9:38:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
    WARNING: The web application  appears to have started a thread named [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1824)
    java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1693)
    java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)



    Jan 13, 2022 9:38:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
    INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.web.WebLookup]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.web.WebLookup]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1435)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1423)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:843)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.findClassIgnoringNotFound(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:90)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1223)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.loadClass(LoaderUtil.java:167)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newInstanceOf(LoaderUtil.java:209)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newCheckedInstanceOf(LoaderUtil.java:230)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Loader.newCheckedInstanceOf(Loader.java:311)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:135)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:133)
```

Comment: What work are you doing inside that method? As the `@Scheduled` doesn't use the `ForkJoinPool` however if you are using parallel streams it will use threads. So I doubt that this is due to Spring code but rather your own code that is (probably unknowningly) using the `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: In the method I am extracting data from a db and process this data but I am not creating any ForkJoinPool, i can see that it comes to a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed" also I have some Exceptions in the stacktrace which I will add to my question above

Comment: Again you don't have to create it if you are using parallel streams (or streams) or something else from the JDK that supports parallelism that will internally use the `ForkJoinPool`. So I'm not saying you are explicitly creating this, but the code you have written is creating that internally.

Comment: Ahh thanks, now I understand. So I have to check where I am using streams. But how can I prevent this or how can I cleanly shutdown these threads when a shutdown call from tomcat comes in?

Comment: Spring Boot configures a `TaskScheduler` for you I'm assuming in all of this that you aren't overriding this or creating one yourself. The auto configured one will be automatically stopped when the application stops. If you have overriden it this might be a cause. What I find weird is that it comes from the sql driver is that doing something to ping things?

Comment: The threads from the pool should be automatically returned, so either you are doing weird things in there (really weird) or you really have misconfigured things.

Comment: As you said correctly I am using the auto configured one. I hope I do no weird things only  getting data from a db, sorting and adding these to custom lists. For this purpose I am using streams() . If I understand you right, normally the ForkJoin Threads which are created by using the streams() should be shutdown by the shutdown of the Taskscheduler?

Comment: No. The threads created by the `TaskScheduler` are shutdown, not the ones from the `ForkJoinPool`. So something is blocking a thread in there, and I also wonder what the `scheduling-1` thread is which seems related to JDBC.